# Download file from URL to SDcard, show progress bar, then after download move to next activity

Tags: java, android

First, i already know how to download, i can show the progress bar, but i cannot switch activity, by default of the download code, when download reach 100% ,it will dismiss the dialogue and remain on that page/layout, i want it to download, and then move to next activity not staying where it is.. So i added a runnable code to change activity after 2seconds of complete download, but it just move to next activity after 2seconds even when download does not excecute.. Help me check the code, and tell me what to do. Thanks

> public class ClockWorkMod extends Activity {
>
> ```
> // button to show progress dialog
> Button btnShowProgress;
>
> // Progress Dialog
> private ProgressDialog pDialog;
> ImageView my_image;
> // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
> public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
>
> // File url to download
> private static String file_url = "http://api.loadedgeek.com/myupgrade/clockworkmod.img";
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.clockworkmod);
>
>     // show progress bar button
>     btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
>     // Image view to show image after downloading
>
>     /**
>      * Show Progress bar click event
>      * */
>     btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             // starting new Async Task
>             new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> /**
>  * Showing Dialog
>  * */
> @Override
> protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
>     switch (id) {
>     case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
>         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
>         pDialog.setMessage("Installing ClockWorkMod. Please Wait...");
>         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         pDialog.setMax(100);
>         pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
>         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>         pDialog.show();
>         return pDialog;
>     default:
>         return null;
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Background Async Task to download file
>  * */
> class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>
>     /**
>      * Before starting background thread
>      * Show Progress Bar Dialog
>      * */
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         showDialog(progress_bar_type);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Downloading file in background thread
>      * */
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
>         int count;
>         try {
>             URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
>             URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
>             conection.connect();
>             // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
>             int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
>
>             // download the file
>             InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
>
>             // Output stream
>             OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/MyUpgrade/clockworkmod.img");
>
>             byte data[] = new byte[1024];
>
>             long total = 0;
>
>             while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
>                 total += count;
>                 // publishing the progress....
>                 // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
>                 publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
>
>                 // writing data to file
>                 output.write(data, 0, count);
>             }
>
>             // flushing output
>             output.flush();
>
>             // closing streams
>             output.close();
>             input.close();
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
>         }
>
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Updating progress bar
>      * */
>     protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
>         // setting progress percentage
>         pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
>    }
>
>     /**
>      * After completing background task
>      * Dismiss the progress dialog
>      * **/
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
>         dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
>         new Handler().
>         postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>           @Override
>           public void run() {
>               Intent i= new Intent(ClockWorkMod.this, ClockWorkModFlash.class);
>               startActivity(i);
>           }
>         }, 2000);
>           }
>
>
>   }
>
>
> {
>
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

create intent to which activity you want to go and start that after download is completed like
suppose you want to go to com.ex.act onceit completes then do

```
Intent i=new Intent("com.ex.act");
startActivity(i);
```